# Trying to Download File via https

Tags: python, authentication, https

I am attempting to download a zip file from a website that sits with an https:// link. I have tried the following but can't seem to get any output. Could anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

> URL = www.somewebsite.com
>
> Download zip file = www.somewebsite.com/output/revisionId=40687821$$Xiiy75&action_id=

```
import requests
url = 'http://somewebsite.org'
user, password = 'bob', 'I love cats'
resp = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password))
```

Comment: please describe exactly how you would download the zip file manually with a web browser.

Is there a welcome page? do you have to enter a username and a password, before you can download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download a file from a non protected url do something like:

```
import requests
url = 'http://somewebsite.org'
user, password = 'bob', 'I love cats'
resp = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password))
with open("result.zip", "wb") as fout:
    fout.write(resp.content)
```

If course you should check whether you got a valid response before writing the zip file.

For a considerable amount of websites with login following recipe will work:
However if asite.com uses too much javascript, this might not necessarily work.

Use a requests session in order to store any session cookies and perform following three steps.

1. GET the login url. This will get potential session cookies or CSRF protection cookies
2. POST to the login url with the username and password.  the name of the forms to be posted depend on the page. Use your web browser in debug mode to learn about the right values that you have to post, this can be more parameters than username and password
3. List item
4. GET the document url and save the result to a file.

On Firefox for example you go to the website you want to login, you press F12 (for debug mode), click on the network tab and then on reload.
You might

Fill in the login form and submit and look in the debug panel for a POST request.

The generic python code would look like.
import requests

```
def login_and_download():
    ses = requests.session()

    # Step 1 get the login page
    rslt = ses.get("https://www.asite.com/login-home")
    # now any potentially required cookie will be set

    if rslt.status_code != 200:
        print("failed getting login page")
        return False

    # for simple pages you can procedd to login
    # for a little more complicated pages you might have to parse the
    # HTML
    # for really annoying pages that use loads of javascript it might be
    # even more complicated


    # Step 2 perform a post request to login
    login_post_url = # This depends on the site you want to connect to. you have analyze the login
                # procedure
    rslt = ses.post(login_post_url)

    if rslt.status_code != 200:
        print("failed logging in")
        return False

    # Step 3 download the url, that you want to get.
    rslt = ses.get(url_of_your_document)
    if rslt.status_code != 200:
        print("failed fetching the file")
        return False
    with open("result.zip", "wb") as fout:
        fout.write(resp.content)
```

Comment: The link i am trying to get to is https://www.asite.com/login-home and within that site has another URL for a zip file.

Comment: When i attempt the download of the file, the zip file downloads but is empty and does not open.

Comment: This is great, i will give it a go. An alternative option is so the website I am trying to get into a file sharing website where files are stored. I have the direct URL to the file. Could python be used in a way where if i 1) manually login via chrome/firefox to my account 2) Using python to directly download the files. Is this a possibility this way?

Comment: Not really in my opinion, it would be firefox having all the session cookies and form data. it would be difficult to transfer them to you python script.

You could use some kind of 'overkill' solution, which would be selenium. This is python controlling a firefox executable, logging in and then you could download.
However this is normally only the 'last' solution if nothing else works.

I suggest, that you change the title of your question to.

How to download a file with python from asite.com .

The solution depends on the site and perhaps somebody knows a solution.

Comment: In fact, the solution might be to use the asite.com web API ( https://upload.asite.com/dmsHelp/About_API.htm ) 

They also have a pdf document explaining the API in detail ( https://adoddleak.asite.com/adoddlepublic/dpd/78zardCk5L9M5I5rqa6 )

However for a person like me who doesn't have an asite.com account it is difficult to test.

I suggest you go through this document. This is probably your way to go.
Afterwards you might post questions specific to this api.

If you use the rest API you can use `requests` if you want to go with the SOAP api look at `zeep`